# How can I cancel from Device.StartTimer?

Tags: c#, android, timer, xamarin

When I use System.Threading.Timer I can stop my timer and start it again:

```
protected override void OnScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)
{
    if (timer == null)
    {
        System.Threading.TimerCallback tcb = OnScrollFinished;
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(tcb, null, 700, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }
    else
    {
        timer.Change(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
        timer.Change(700, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }
}
```

What is the best way to stop Device.StartTimer and start it again?

Comment: You can use or Thread.Sleep or you can set in constructor the period parameter.

Comment: No, I can't sleep. Application must work

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I am guessing you are referring to Device.StartTime in XamarinForms. The way to stop or continue a recurring task is determined by what the second argument returns:

```
// run task in 2 minutes
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), () =>
{
    if (needsToRecur)
    {
        // returning true will fire task again in 2 minutes.
        return true;
    }

    // No longer need to recur. Stops firing task
    return false; 
});
```

If you want to temporarily stop this timer, and then fire it again after some time, you will have to call `Device.StartTimer` again.  It would be nice to wrap this into its own class where you can use a private member to determine if a continuous task is still running. Something like this:

```
public class DeviceTimer
{
  readonly Action _Task;
  readonly List<TaskWrapper> _Tasks = new List<TaskWrapper>();
  readonly TimeSpan _Interval;
  public bool IsRecurring { get; }
  public bool IsRunning => _Tasks.Any(t => t.IsRunning);

  public DeviceTimer(Action task, TimeSpan interval, 
    bool isRecurring = false, bool start = false)
  {
    _Task = task;
    _interval = interval;
    IsRecurring = isRecurring;
    if (start)
      Start();
  }

  public void Restart()
  {
    Stop();
    Start();
  }

  public void Start()
  {
    if (IsRunning)
      // Already Running
      return;

    var wrapper = new TaskWrapper(_Task, IsRecurring, true);
    _Tasks.Add(wrapper);

    Device.StartTimer(_interval, wrapper.RunTask);
  }

  public void Stop()
  {
    foreach (var task in _Tasks)
      task.IsRunning = false;
    _Tasks.Clear();
  }


  class TaskWrapper
  {
    public bool IsRunning { get; set; }
    bool _IsRecurring;
    Action _Task;
    public TaskWrapper(Action task, bool isRecurring, bool isRunning)
    {
      _Task = task;
      _IsRecurring = isRecurring;
      IsRunning = isRunning;
    }

    public bool RunTask()
    {
      if (IsRunning)
      {
        _Task();
        if (_IsRecurring)
          return true;
      }

      // No longer need to recur. Stop
      return IsRunning = false;
    }
  }         
}
```

Comment: problem I am facing here is if use navigates to another page even, this timer is kept on and continues running. Your solution looks promising but question what action/event should call Stop() function when user navigates from the page. If I use OnDisappearing action, it is also triggered when screen is locked or app is taken to background. I cant use backbutton pressed event as well, because it wont be fired on androd if the software back button is pressed. what do you think?

Comment: I updated your code with my experiment results. Should you have any objection, feel free to unedit.

Comment: Why a list of tasks  `List<TaskWrapper> _Tasks` is used? This should work with only one too?